# Subversion size explosion by shifting around directories; myth or fact?

Tags: svn

I recently had to re-factor some code from a previous maintainer and initially I had to do a lot of shifting directories and renaming et-all. It was relatively a small amount of code so comparing sizes didn't really reveal much. Given that subversion will always preserve each version, won't this explode the size?

I'm assuming that

`repo/trunk/bobbyapple`

moved to

`repo/branches/oldapple`

would be considered different histories based off of path and that subversion would preserve these differently (move = copy+delete). Thus if one shifts around large directories, this quickly can explode the size?

Comment: Just to clarify - you're using svn rather than the operating system to carry out the moves? (i.e.: You're using "svn move" or equivalent?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Copying is essentially free in SVN, and changes are stored as diffs.  So no, this won't "explode" the size.

Comment: Gracious, for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

SVN Creates "Cheap Copies" that doesn't *really* make a copy of anything, it just creates a new version of the files that has been altered in the copy. It's quoted here:

> Subversion's repository has a special design. When you copy a directory, you don't need to worry about the repository growing huge—Subversion doesn't actually duplicate any data. Instead, it creates a new directory entry that points to an existing tree. If you're a Unix user, this is the same concept as a hard-link. From there, the copy is said to be “lazy”. That is, if you commit a change to one file within the copied directory, then only that file changes—the rest of the files continue to exist as links to the original files in the original directory.

**refer:** http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch04s02.html#svn-ch-4-sect-2.1